# Getting a list from a text file in java

Tags: java, list

I currently have a database access class to pull the data from my list listed like so:

```
Pique:CBPique.png:41:22:55:91
Ronaldo:STRonaldo.png:89:85:92:91
...
```

The class is as follows:

```
class DatabaseAccess {




static DatabaseAccess dataAccessor;


static DatabaseAccess getInstance(String dbPath) {

    if (dataAccessor == null) {
        dataAccessor = new DatabaseAccess(dbPath);
    }

    return dataAccessor;
}


private DatabaseAccess(String dbPath) {
    dbLocation = dbPath;
}


List<FootballPlayer> getCards() {
    return this.getData();
}


private List<FootballPlayer> getData() {

    List<FootballPlayer> theData = new ArrayList<FootballPlayer>();

    // create a Scanner and grab the data . . .

    Scanner scanner = null;

    String dataPath = dbLocation + File.separator + "text" + File.separator + "players.db";

    String imagePath = dbLocation + File.separator + "images";

    try {

        scanner = new Scanner(new File(dataPath));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) { 

        System.out.println(fnf.getMessage());


        System.exit(0);
    }

    // scan players.db file line-by-line

    scanner.useDelimiter("\n");

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {

        String line = scanner.next().trim();

       // trim used to trim for new line

        String[] bits = line.split(":");

        String t = bits[0];                    // title
        String imgFileName = bits[1];          // image file name
        int pa = Integer.parseInt(bits[2]);     // pace
        int sh = Integer.parseInt(bits[3]);     // shooting
        int dr = Integer.parseInt(bits[4]);    // dribbling
        int ph = Integer.parseInt(bits[5]);    // physical

        // create the image

        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(imagePath + File.separator + imgFileName);

        // Create the business object

        FootballPlayer player = new FootballPlayer(t, img, pa, sh, dr, ph);

        // add it to the list ... simple as ...

        theData.add(player);
    }

    scanner.close(); 

    return theData;

}
```

What I want to do is pull the data from this list and display it / use it within another class, for example pulling the image file names for use, or even displaying all the data in a list.

Been struggling with it and any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a way your Scanner may look like: It reads the file and saves line per line into an ArrayList.

```
    ArrayList<String> singleParts = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        int index = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( new File("files/"+filename+".txt") );
        while ( scanner.hasNextLine() )  {
            String actualLine = scanner.nextLine();
            singleParts.add(actualLine);
        }
        scanner.close(); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Throwable te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
    }
```

After this, you could iterate through your ArrayList line per line, char per char. To make things easier, you could use your ':' as a seperator.

Example first line, Name:

```
String name = "";
boolean saved = false;

for(int line = 0; line < singleParts.size(); line++) {
    for(int char = 0; char < singleParts.get(line).length(); char++) {
         if(char<singleParts.get(line).indexOf(':') {
             name += singleParts.get(line).charAt(char);
         }
    }
}
```

To get the rest, you have a lot of possibilities. For example, cut away the already used chars and reuse the loop similar to this one.

Answer (score 1):

Does your Player object have attributes/properties that are unique, such as name or ID?

Since you already have the `Player` object containing all the properties you need, why not put it in a `HashMap` instead of `Arraylist`, considering if you have a **key** to identify the specific `Player`?

```
FootballPlayer player = new FootballPlayer(t, img, pa, sh, dr, ph);
yourKey = t    // an identifier to you player, in this case i used t for example
playersMap.put(t,player);
```

This way you can easily retrieve your Player by using

```
Player myPlayer = playersMap.get(yourKey)

// you can then get the properties of the Player
myPlayer.getImg();
myPlayer.getPa();
```

Hope this helps